# RestKit creates NSManagedObject duplicates on response

Tags: objective-c, post, duplicates, restkit

I'm sending an Alarm object to a server and the server will give me a response with a json:
"status" -> "ok"
"alarm" -> 
I set the identificationAttributes and the managedObjectCache. But Restkit still creates a duplicate object. Is there something else I need to take care of?

```
-(void)sendAlarm:(Alarm *)alarm{

RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:((InsulyneAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).persistentStoreCoordinator];

[objectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
RKObjectMapping *alarmRequestMapping = [alarm alarmObjectMapping];
RKRequestDescriptor * requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:alarmRequestMapping objectClass:[Alarm class] rootKeyPath:@"alarm" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[AlarmResponse alarmResponseMappingInObjectStore:objectStore]  method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxx.com"]];
manager.managedObjectStore = objectStore;

[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = manager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

objectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:context];

NSMutableURLRequest* alarmRequest = [manager requestWithObject:alarm method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"/index.php" parameters:nil];




RKManagedObjectRequestOperation* operation = [manager managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:alarmRequest managedObjectContext:context success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
 NSLog(@"Success sending alarm");
    AlarmResponse *result = [mappingResult firstObject];
    NSLog(@"status is: %@, alarm time is: %@", [result status],[result.alarm alarmTime]);
 } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 NSLog(@"Failure saving post: %@", error.localizedDescription);
 }];

 [[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperation:operation];
}


+(RKObjectMapping *)alarmResponseMappingInObjectStore:(RKManagedObjectStore *)objectStore{
RKEntityMapping* alarmMapping = [Alarm alarmEntityMappingInManagedStore:objectStore];

RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[AlarmResponse class]];
[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"status"]];
[responseMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"alarm" toKeyPath:@"alarm" withMapping:alarmMapping]];
return responseMapping;
}

+(RKEntityMapping *)alarmEntityMappingInManagedStore:(RKManagedObjectStore *)objectStore{
RKEntityMapping* alarmMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Alarm" inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
// NOTE: When your source and destination key paths are symmetrical, you can use addAttributesFromArray: as a shortcut instead of addAttributesFromDictionary:
[alarmMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"authorEmail", @"recipientEmail", @"message", @"alarmTime" ]];
alarmMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"alarmTime"];
return alarmMapping;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have both object and entity mappings? If you're using Core Data all of your mappings should be entity mappings...

Comment: Becuase I don't have and don't want to have the status stored in Core Data. However part of the Json response is a CoreData entity, which I don't want to be duplicated. Currently, matching the response from the server duplicates my Alarm object in CoreData.

Comment: Ok, I guess if it works (I didn't actually expect it would) then fine. What is the data type of `alarmTime` in the model? Can you not add actual identifiers to the alarms rather than using the time (which can be changed)?

Comment: The alarmTime is an NSDate. what do you mean by actual identifiers? do you mean the ObjectID of the NSManagedObject?

Comment: Just some id (just an incrementing number would work). Something that is static and cannot be changed. The existing alarm info could all be changed or isn't suitable for identification purposes. That said, RestKit should be able to match if the dates are identical.